# Website double-scrolling on Chrome using scroll-snap-type

Tags: html, css, scroll, scroll-snap, scroll-snap-type

I want my sections to take the whole page and as soon as the user scrolls up or down, the previous/next section comes up. It works perfectly on Firefox and on Chromium-Edge, but when I tested it on Chrome, it always skips a section (goes from section1 to section 3 and from section 3 back to section 1). What can I do to solve this problem?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="page container">
    <div class="section section1">
       ...
    </div>

    <div class="section section1">
       ...
    </div>

    <div class="section section2">
       ...
    </div>

    <div class="section section3">
       ...
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
    .container{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;

  /*  Scroll Snap  */

  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.section{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

here is the website if anyone wants to see by themselves : [Open in Firefox and/or Chrome to see difference](https://felixpoirier.ca/index.html)

Comment: I think this has just been fixed in Chrome. At least it doesn't seem to be double scrolling for me in Chrome anymore. Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q8L752wy/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitely a bug in Chrome. The offender seems to be `background-color` (!) property set on the container element.

For some inexplicable reasons its presence triggers overscrolling... BUT only on a `wheel`-kind scroll. The keyboard one (either with KeyUp/Down or PageUp/Down) works fine.

Here's SRE; try scrolling the page, then press 'Fix Chrome' button, then scroll one more time - and see the difference. In Chrome 86 (`Version 86.0.4240.111 (Official Build) (64-bit)`, to be precise), at least.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.break-things {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.item {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  font-size: 7rem;
  height: 77vh; 
}

.item1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.item2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.item3 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header><button type=button>FIX CHROME SCROLL SNAP</button></header>
  <div class="container break-things">
    <div class="item item1">Hello World</div>
    <div class="item item2">Hello World</div>
    <div class="item item3">Hello World</div>
  </div>
  <script>
   let isChromeBroken = true;
   document.querySelector('button').onclick = (ev) => {
     isChromeBroken = !isChromeBroken;
     ev.target.textContent = `${isChromeBroken ? 'FIX' : 'BREAK'} CHROME SCROLL SNAP`;
     document.querySelector('.container').classList.toggle('break-things');   
   }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow thnaks a lot! you are right, the problem seems to come from the background-color property. As soon as I remove that, everything works perfectly! Would never have thought of that myself. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Big thanks to you sir! It still isnt fixed it seems.

Comment: @Wolle No, it's not; the comment at the question is misleading. Not sure why one created a separate fiddle anyway: if the issue is fixed, it's fixed in that snippet as well. And yes, Canary v90 still has it (just checked).

Comment: @raina77ow i got that bug in a project right now, setting the background-color to another container worked. Edge Chromium (Version 88.0.705.63) does not have that problem, but Chrome (Version 88.0.4324.150) and Brave (Version 1.19.92 Chromium: 88.0.4324.152) do.
ps: i was not referring to that comment on the question but to the timeframe (I read 2017 somehow...)

Comment: @Wolle Well, two things about this bug seem to be true: it's relatively old and it's Chromium-specific. Just checked it with somewhat obsolete version of Opera (73.0.3856.344). I wouldn't be surprised if Edge team fixed it in their branch though.

Comment: Using Chrome 89.0.4389.90 and it appears to be working just fine now.

Comment: Just checked the snippet, it's still broken - on the same version of Chrome. How exactly you're trying to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in Chrome and Opera on Windows (not Mac). But if I make each block of the page scrollable horizontally, the problem is solved.

As [raina77ow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64582013/6874959) wrote in his answer to this case, the bug fires only on `wheel` events. But in my case it does not depend on any background parameters.

For now I have only found a solution based on this:

```css
html {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.page {
  position: relative;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.page::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none
}

.page::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% + 1px);
  height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="page">
    Page 1
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    Page 2
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    Page 3
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    Page 4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: An interesting idea, but I don't think horizontal scrolling has a real effect on the OP's problem. Just tried adding background-color to your snippet, got the same overscrolling behavior on wheel events. I can only guess here that presence of background for some reason triggers duplicate processing of this event in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Below snippet solved the issue for me.

```js
var canScroll = true;
    var scrollContainer = document.querySelector('html')
    scrollContainer.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
    if (canScroll) {
        scrollContainer.scrollBy(0, e.deltaY);
        canScroll = false;
        setTimeout(() => {
            canScroll = true;
        }, 800);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    }, { passive: false });
```

```css
html {
        height: 100%;
        scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
          scroll-behavior: smooth;
        -ms-scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
    }

    div#section-1,div#section-2,div#section-3,div#section-4,div#section-5 {
        padding: 0;
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        font-family: 'LexiaLight';
        width: 100%;
    }

    div#section-1, div#section-2, div#section-3, div#section-4, div#section-5 {
      scroll-snap-align: start;
      scroll-snap-stop: always;
    }

    div#section-1 {
        background: #264653;
    }

    div#section-2 {
        background: #2a9d8f;
    }

    div#section-3 {
        background: #e9c46a;
    }

    div#section-4 {
        background: #f4a261;
    }

    div#section-5 {
        background: #e76f51;
    }

    div#section-1, div#section-2, div#section-3, div#section-4, div#section-5{
      scroll-snap-align: start;
        scroll-snap-stop: always;
    }
```

```html
<div id="section-1"></div>
<div id="section-2"></div>
<div id="section-3"></div>
<div id="section-4"></div>
<div id="section-5"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This nearly broke me down :)

I simply removed the `background` property set on the `container` element and it was fixed.