# Scroll Snap Full Screen Always Scrolls 2 Sections

Tags: html, css, fullscreen, scroll-snap

The problem is shown here:

https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/yLLqqgP

This is the important part:

```
    html {
        scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    }
    section {
        height: 100vh;
        scroll-snap-align: start;
    }
```

When setting height of section > 120, or similar this issue can get fixed, but this is a hack.

When I start scrolling, with a scroll wheel, then it always scrolls two sections, which makes the whole logic unusable.

I am using Chrome: 86.0.4240.183.

This codepen example is from: https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/ which is a very well known ressource for css examples.

Comment: Here there are some more ressources that show the same problem: https://codepen.io/michellebarker/full/PowYKXJ

Comment: Funnily enough it works in Microsoft Edge Version 86.0.622.63 which also has Webkit engine. This makes the whole situation even stranger.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug in Chrome unfortunately, caused by using either `html` or a container with a `background-color` property for the scroll container. It only affects scroll wheels and not trackpads or touch scrolling on mobile. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64581125/website-double-scrolling-on-chrome-using-scroll-snap-type) for a demonstration of the problem.

The simplest solution is to just use a nested container to hold the scroll, although, bizarrely, you may notice that the scroll-snap now has a small delay on it. This is the best that can be done with the current implementation:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

h1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>1</h1>
  <h1>2</h1>
  <h1>3</h1>
  <h1>4</h1>
</div>
```

The problem is unfortunately compounded once you realise that `100vh` is also non-static (read: extremely janky) on some mobile browsers due to the implementation of retracting UI, potentially leading to unstyled gaps as the `html` layer shows through before the container fills up the remaining space. I've spent hours wrestling with this issue this year and have yet to come up with a totally satisfactory solution, settling for media queries to reset back to `html` in most cases and targeting any edge cases with JS.

Here's one possible media query you could add for that:

```
@media (hover: none) and (pointer: coarse) {
  html {
    overflow: auto;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  }

  .container {
    height: auto;
    display: contents;
    scroll-snap-type: unset;
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you think about JS solutions like Fullpage JS?

Comment: I try to avoid JS for any styling unless absolutely necessary. Fullpage seems to have solved the `100vh` issue by blocking UI retraction entirely which isn't great IMO, and the performance can also be a bit sluggish on mobile. Maybe I was too pessimistic in my answer; I'd still much rather use the native scrolling API in this state than revert to a full JS solution and take a performance hit. When *really* I want to stop `vh` sized elements jumping on mobile I overwrite `100vh` with a `window.innerHeight` CSS Var and just accept that they will not always line up perfectly with the screen.