# double scroll snap chrome bug

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, scroll-snap

I have some issues considering scroll-snap-align in css, probably due to a familiar bug in chrome.
I have found two ways to make the scroll-snap-align work, but both ways won't properly.

1. Option 1 - use the scroll-snap-type in the html tag:

```
html {
   scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

article {
   /* empty */
}

section {
   scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

2. Option 2 - use the scroll-snap-type in the container (article) tag:

```
html {
   /* empty */
}

article {
   scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

section {
   scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

**The problem is** that option 1 cause the double-scroll bug in chrome, and I haven't found a way to fix it (changing the background color didn't work for me),
and option 2 just won't do anything at all, same as if I didn't write this lines of code.

I have also tried playing with `overflow-y`, `overscroll-behavior-y` or changing the `height` of the container, but none of them fixed the issue.

I'd be very thankful for anyone who will try to help me :)

P.S
I'm using create-react-app if it matters somehow.

Comment: What is the chrome double-scroll bug?

Comment: What is your HTML structure? Is `section` a direct child of `article`?

Comment: The double-scroll bug is described well in here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64581125/website-double-scrolling-on-chrome-using-scroll-snap-type

And yes to the second question. The tree is basically: 
html -> body -> { ...some divs... } -> article -> section

Comment: I'm using Chrome 89.0.4389.90. Looking at the example in that post, it appears to be working just fine now. Can you provide a full snippet of your code that shows the bug?

Comment: My version is the same, and the code is long but you can see the result here: https://msimyan.com/ (in the inspector of course). notice that the problem appears only when you're using the mouse's scroll, not the scroll bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is you need to make sure the element you have set to scroll snap is actually the one being scrolled.

In your case, although you placed the `scroll-snap-type` property on your `article` element, the `article` is free to stack its content and fill its parent. Thus, when you scroll, the `html` element is being scrolled, not the `article` element.

To fix this, simply add

```css
article {
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    height: 100vh; /* match the height of the screen */
    overflow-y: scroll; /* force it to scroll */
}
```

This will work as you expect. However, because your `footer` element is outside the `article`, when you reach the bottom, it will scroll the `html` element to show it. Then, if you scroll up on the `article` and not the `footer`, the `footer` will remain and your `article` will only be partially visible.

Therefore, I would suggest you actually add the above styling to your `div#root` element, and add `scroll-snap-align: start;` to your `footer`. This should make the scrolling work nicely.

Comment: OK I understand much better how scrollbars work (still don't understand why I must put `height: 100vh` but whatever).
It also worked when I put this code under `body` and not `article` which includes the footer, but the problem is now different - the navbar is above my scroll-bar :(
I tried to add the next code to my css:
`body::-webkit-scrollbar { z-index: 1; }`
and changed the z-index to any number, but it won't help.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Another problem I found out - the `scrollIntoView` function won't work, I guess because we don't scroll the `html` anymore but the `body` instead.
Should I just give up on the scroll-snap and finish with it?

Comment: No! [Never give up. Never surrender!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9fdcIwHKd_s&ab_channel=retroelectrical) Every element can be scrolled. By default, the size of an element will be large enough to show all of its contents; therefore, it will have no need to scroll. This is true for all but the `html` element, which is bound by the viewport size. This is why the `html` element is the default element that scrolls.  We set the height of the element you want to scroll so that it doesn't expand large enough to show all of its content without scrolling.

Comment: Additionally, you have to tell it not to show the overflow, or again, the scrolling will default to the next parent set to scroll. We used `100vh` because that will always be the height of the viewport (the entire window). The navbar is above your scrollbar because it is above the element that is scrolling. You can move the navbar inside the scrolling element before positioning it so it will be included in the scroll. The `scrollIntoView` function must be called on the scrolling element. Something like `document.querySelector('body').scrollIntoView()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, you really helped me :)